# How Ahrefs/MOZ/SEMRUSH are Able To Crawl SERP Data As Google Limists The Searches

Tags: web-crawler

How Marketing Tools Giants, such as Ahrefs, Moz, SEMRUSH and so on are able to crawl SERP data for thousands of keywords as Google is even limiting Standalone Users if they're making few dozen searches each minute. Are they using some Official Google API, or purchasing the data or what...

As we can fetch the data from SERP with ease by creating a simple file_get_contents in PHP but what about the limits.

```
$file = file_get_contents('https://google.com?s=example')
```

Answer (score 1):

Crawling Google with big amount of keywords is really big challenge. You should have your proxy pool which is not flagged by search engines before.

Generally, big brands use 3rd party services which handle all stuff for them.

For instance, we as AvesAPI, handle scraping millions of keywords on Google everyday, and export the results as JSON for our customers. We also work with so many big brands in the market.